# c programming , word count

Tags: c, word-count

> Write a C program named “mywc.c” simulating the “wc” command taking some options and text file as arguments.
>   If no option is given, mywc outputs the number of lines, words and characters in the given file as well as the file name separated by a blank space.
>   When the –l option is used, mywc can output the number of lines;
>   When the –w option is used, mywc can output the number of words;
>   When the –c option is used, mywc can output the number of characters.
>   If the given file doesn’t exist, it gives an error message with program name, text file name and the causal separated by colon. 
>   The program should also meet the following requirements.
>   (1) Use structure to store the number of lines, words, and characters.
>   (2) Characters only include letters and digits.
>   (3) The order of options does not matter.
>   (4) When take the screenshot, always show the text first.
>   The output could be like this:
>
> (omitted)

I did this code but not working

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    char buff[255];
    char command[255];
    int c=0,i,j=0;
    int line=0;
    int word=0;
    char ch;
    char fileName[255];
    printf("*********************************************\n");
    printf("Enter command (Example -c input.txt)\n");
    printf("-c for Number of character in file \n");
    printf("-w for Number of words in file \n");
    printf("-l for Number of lines in file \n");
    printf("*********************************************\n");
    scanf("%s",command);
    //Extracting file name
    if(command[2]==' ') {
        if(command[1]=='l' || command[1]=='w' || command[1]=='c') {
            while(command[i]!='\0') {
                if(i>2) {
                    fileName[j]=command[i];
                    i++;
                }
                fileName[i]='\0';
            }
            printf("*********************************************\n");
            printf("File Name You have provided is:%s\n",fileName);
            printf("*********************************************\n");
            fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
            if(fp) {
                while(!feof(fp )) {
                    memset(buff, '\0', sizeof( buff) );
                    fgets(buff, 255, (FILE*)fp);
                    for(i = 0; buff[ i ]; i++)
                    {
                        if (buff[i] == '\n')
                            line ++,word++;
                        else if (buff[i] == ' ')
                            word ++;
                        else
                            c++;
                    }
                }
                fclose(fp);
                if(command[0]=='-' && command[1]=='w')
                    printf("Number of words in file: %i\n", word);
                else if(command[0]=='-' && command[1]=='c')
                    printf("Number of characters in file: %i\n",(c-2));
                else if(command[0]=='-' && command[1]=='l')
                    printf("Number of lines in file: %i \n", line);
                else {
                    printf("Number of words in file: %i\n", word);
                    printf("Number of characters in file: %i\n",(c-2));
                    printf("Number of lines in file: %i \n", line);
                }
                printf("*********************************************\n");
            } else
                printf("File not found");
            return;
        }
```

Every time I ran this code with a menu option and text file, I always get a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error. How can I avoid this?

Comment: And what is the question ?

Comment: EVERY TIME I RAN THIS CODE WITH A MENU OPTION AND TEXT FILE, I WOULD ALWAYS GET A "SEGMENTATION FAULT (CORE DUMPED)" ERROR, PLEASE HELP

Comment: yes please, that would help alot

Comment: @Erine Henien please, don't use caps lock!

Comment: my bad, caps lock was on

Comment: You're using `i` without initializing it.

Comment: Please do yourself a favor and format your code correctly.

Comment: Also, main should be `int main(int arc, char * argv[])`

Comment: @FiddlingBits i just did but its still not working

Comment: @ErineHenien.: Have you added the modifications I mentioned

Comment: @Garf365 just did still not working

Comment: @ErineHenien It's normal, it doesn't change anything about your segfault but it's the correct way of doing a main. I didn't say anymore cause answer juste below seams to help you

Comment: @coderredoc im still confused on what to do, is there email i can contact you with

Comment: @ErineHenien.: check my answer

Comment: @coderredoc, did it but still getting same error

Answer (score 1):

Use `fgets` so that all strings are read in a line. Here only 1 string is read.

Or get the command step by step. Then look for the operation.

Note: initialize `i`.

***Problem***

And another thing `scanf` reads until a linebreak/space/tab is found. SO file name is not read in `command`.

```
while( fgets(buffer, BUFFERSIZE , stdin) ) /* break with ^D or ^Z */
{
  //process buffer
}
```

### ***Where is it going wrong?***

```
scanf("%s",command); //use fgets here you are not reading everything here

//Extracting file name
if(command[2]==' ') {

if(command[1]=='l'||command[1]=='w'||command[1]=='c') {
while(command[i]!='\0')
{
if(i>2) {
fileName[j]=command[i];
i++;
}
fileName[i]='\0';
}
```

For understanding what is going wrong you just put a print statement after reading `command` and then print it and comment out rest of the code.

Comment: @ErineHenien.; got it?

Comment: im getting these errors too ./hw71.c: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./hw71.c: line 4: `int main()'

Comment: @ErineHenien.: listen can I discuss with you later..rightnow I am kinda busy..the thing..get the whole string "-c example.c" in a string fully...